# problem with GET / POST does not receive data with php

Tags: php, post, get

i have problem here, this is mi code:
tried to send the form data to another PHP file where it receives them and uploads to the sql server but it seems not to work

```
<form id="modal" action="revisaorden.php" method="post">
                            <form id="modal" action="revisaorden.php" method="post" >
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    Ingrese su nombre.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="direccion">Direccion</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="direccion" id="direccion" placeholder="Direccion" required>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    Ingrese su direccion.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="telefono">Telefono</label>
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Telefono" required>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    Ingrese su numero de telefono.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="observaciones">Observaciones</label>
                                <textarea type="textarea" class="form-control" name="observaciones" id="observaciones" placeholder=""></textarea>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="txtCambio">Requiero cambio de:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtCambio" id="txtcambio">
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer ">
                            <button type="submit" onclick="location.href='revisaorden.php?$total=<?php echo $total ?>&$cantidad=<?php echo $cantidad ?>&$item=<?php echo $item ?>&nombre&direccion&telefono&email&observaciones&txtcambio'" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Enviar</button>
                            </div>
                            </form>
                        </form>
```

here you should send in POST the form data to the following file: revisaorden.php with the following code to read them.

```
<?php
        //codigo para el envio de los datos al sistema
        $v1 = ($_GET['nombre']);$v2 = ($_GET['direccion']);$v3 = ($_GET['telefono']);$v4 = ($_GET['email']);$v5 = ($_GET['observaciones']);
        $v6 = ($_GET['txtcambio']);
        $v7 = ($_GET['$item']);
        $v8 = ($_GET['$cantidad']);
        $v9 = ($_GET['$total']);
                /* Here the data is uploaded to the server 
                $client = new Clientes();
                $client->addClientes($v1, $v2, $v3, $v4);
                //echo $client;*/
            echo $v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5,$v6,$v7,$v8,$v9;
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this form is `<form id="modal" action="revisaorden.php" method="post">` you must use $_POST to receive data, like this.

```
$v1 = ($_POST['nombre']);
$v2 = ($_POST['direccion']);
$v3 = ($_POST['telefono']);
$v4 = ($_POST['email']);
$v5 = ($_POST['observaciones']);
$v6 = ($_POST['txtcambio']);
$v7 = ($_POST['$item']);
$v8 = ($_POST['$cantidad']);
$v9 = ($_POST['$total']);
```

to receive data.

Comment: it does not work, when loading the next page it tells me that the indeces are empty, in an error